# How to fetch api data by passing variables (parameters)?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout

I am fetching api data for sports player for which I need to pass unique `player id`. Currently, I have to pass `pid` manually which fetches only one player's data at a time. But I would like to fetch multiple players data and display it in `listView`.

API endpoint is: https://cricapi.com/api/playerStats?apikey=&pid=0000.

I am able to parse above url, fetch it's result and display in UI properly, but I want to fetch multiple players data and not just one.

Code to fetch api:

```
FetchJson() async {
  var response = await http.get('https://cricapi.com/api/playerStats? 
    apikey=&pid=1111');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    String responseBody = response.body;
    var responseJson = jsonDecode(responseBody);
    name = responseJson['name'];
    playingRole = responseJson['playingRole'];
    battingStyle = responseJson['battingStyle'];
    country = responseJson['country'];
    imageURL = responseJson['imageURL'];
```

Json snippet is:

> {
>     "pid": 1111,
>     "country": "Australia",
>     "profile": "\n\n blah",
>     "imageURL": "https://www.cricapi.com/playerpic/1111.jpg",

What I am trying to achieve is, to display multiple players profile dynamically instead of passing hardcoded `pid` in the code, so that the UI will display multiple players in `listview`.

How to pass different `pid` dynamically in the url endpoint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `String` interpolation and receiving the id as parameter. You can read more about it [here](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#strings).

```
FetchJson(int playerId) async {
  var response = await http.get('https://cricapi.com/api/playerStats? 
    apikey=&pid=$playerId');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    String responseBody = response.body;
    var responseJson = jsonDecode(responseBody);
    name = responseJson['name'];
    playingRole = responseJson['playingRole'];
    battingStyle = responseJson['battingStyle'];
    country = responseJson['country'];
    imageURL = responseJson['imageURL'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I am calling `FetchJson()` inside `initState()` as
  `void initState() {
    int pid;
    FetchJson(pid);
  }`.  which is throwing an error as: `NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("batting")` . I know somehow ['data'] is `null`, but not sure how suddenly it started to throw this error. The entire code is here: https://pastebin.com/q5zEPmiw .  @miguelpruivo

Comment: I stumbled upon a roadblock while implementing solution for which I've asked new question.