# How to pass variable(&id) from one api to another to fetch corresponding data?

Tags: json, api, dart, flutter

I want to display players stats in `listview` for which I am consuming this api: https://cricapi.com/api/playerStats?apikey=apikey&pid=pid

Output of above api is:

```
{
  "pid": xxxx,
  "profile": "profile description",
  "imageURL": "https://www.cricapi.com/playerpic/xxxx.jpg",
```

`pid` for each player is retrieved from another api:

https://cricapi.com/api/playerFinder?apikey=apikey&name=playerName

Output of above api is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "pid": xxxx,
      "fullName": "Firstname Lastname",
```

Currently, I am passing hardcoded `pid` in first api to display player's stats and code for it is:

```
FetchJson() async {
var response = await http.get(
    'https://cricapi.com/api/playerStats?apikey=apikey&pid=1111');

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  String responseBody = response.body;
  var responseJson = jsonDecode(responseBody);
  pid = responseJson['pid'];
  name = responseJson['name'];
  playingRole = responseJson['playingRole'];
  battingStyle = responseJson['battingStyle'];
  country = responseJson['country'];
  imageURL = responseJson['imageURL'];
  data = responseJson;

  var stats = data['data']['batting'];
  var testStats = stats['tests'];
  var odiStats = stats['ODIs'];
  var tStats = stats['T20Is'];

  // T20 Stats

  matches_t = tStats['Mat'];
  runs_t = tStats['Runs'];
  half_t = tStats['50'];
  century_t = tStats['100'];
  highest_t = tStats['HS'];
  avg_t = tStats['Ave'];
```

And I am calling `FetchJson()` inside `initState()`.

I tried solution given on my similar / earlier question [How to fetch api data by passing variables (parameters)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944759/how-to-fetch-api-data-by-passing-variables-parameters/53945341#53945341), but that led me to a different path. I cannot implement that solution, since there's no way for me to return `pid` through first api that will be received by `FetchJson()`.

My question is:

How to retrieve `pid` from second api (playerFinder) and feed it to first api (playerStats) and how to make use of that `pid` so that instead of passing hardcoded `pid`, I can pass `pid` as variable and can display multiple players stats in UI?

Required code is here : https://pastebin.com/iU8x9U8z

I want to show players stats in UI but currently I am passing hardcoded `playerid` which is showing me only one player's stats, but I would like to show different players stats.

**********UPDATE *************

As an alternate solution, I am now using list of `pids` and parsed those using `map` and passing them to `FetchJson()` inside for loop, as below:

```
var playerIds = [{"pid":35320},{"pid":28114},{"pid":28779},{"pid":28763},{"pid":30176},{"pid":7133},{"pid":5390}]

@override
  void initState() {
    var intIds = playerIds.map<int>((m) => m['pid'] as int).toList();
    for (int i = 0; i < intIds.length; i++) {
      FetchJson(intIds[i]);
    }
  }

FetchJson(int ids) async {
    print(ids);
    var response = await http.get(
        'https://cricapi.com/api/playerStats?apikey=apikey&pid=$ids');
....
}
```

The issue I am now facing with this approach is, its taking last `pid` from the list and displaying its data in UI repeatedly. The expected output I want to see is: players data for all `pids` in UI and I am not sure how to achieve this.

Complete referenced code here: https://pastebin.com/kFYBfHuf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer is to create `Maps` from both sets of api's down to desirable player data then use a switch statement as written below similar to a `where` clause in order to identify matching data.

The big problem is that you need to identify matching data items in both api's.  In my example I've assumed it may be a players name or it could be their team and team number, but there has to be something that validates you are looking at differing data points for the same player.

```
switch(variable_expression) { 
   case name = full_name: { 
      // statements; 
   } 
   break; 

   case constant_expr2: { 
      //statements; 
   } 
   break; 

   default: { 
      //statements;  
   }
   break; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I agree with you about identifying matching data items from both apis which seems to be more complex that I thought earlier. As an alternate solution, I am now using list of `pids` and parsed it using `map` and passing those inside a loop, which is working partially for me. Could you please take a look at updated question and help me fixing new issue am facing ? @Charles Jr